# Add one class at a time with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, class

I have a function that add a class (a animation) on the element, but it is not working as planned.

**I want that the user add one class at a time.** How verify this? I really don't know how to do that with raw Javascript. With jQuery would be easy, I think, because jQuery has the brilliant [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function.

I try to remove the class when the animation stops, but the user still can add multiple classes. And so, there will be several classes during the animation and will be removed only when the animations are gone. Look:

```
el.classList.add("test", anotherClass);
el.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", function() {
    el.classList.remove(anotherClass);
}, true);`
```

Basically, what im trying to do:

Button click > Add class > When finished or interrupted by another button (and, therefore, new class), remove class or add the new

*Obs.: I'm noob with JavaScript, so, please, do not explain with difficult words.*

Answer (score 0):

Try something simple:

```
function setSingleClass(el, singleClass)
{
    if (!el._isSingleClassSet) {
        el.classList.add(singleClass);
        el._isSingleClassSet = 1
        el.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", function () {
            el.classList.remove(singleClass);
            el._isSingleClassSet = 0
        }, true);
    }
}
```